# Add a quality filter for single, long-paragraph questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quality-filter

**Current situation**

I often encounter questions, especially by new users, that are just a single very long paragraph, or a single very long paragraph followed by *"Thanks"* or *"Can anyone help me?"*. I have a hard time reading and understanding these kinds of questions, and using multiple paragraphs would likely make this easier.

It has been proven that for other readers as well, longer paragraphs harm readability<sup>1</sup>. This is especially significant for dyslexics ([5-10% of the population](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2528651/)), and non-native readers (which there are a lot of on Stack Overflow).

While this can be mitigated by editing these questions, that requires time of an experienced user, the edit will be done by another person than the OP, and in the meantime the question might be read less, understood less, downvoted or closed because of it's lesser readability.

See this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/755217/long-single-paragraph-questions) that identifies long, single paragraph questions, so you can see what kind of questions I'm talking about. <sub>(Note: I'm not experienced with SEDE, so I couldn't correct the length by the length of the HTML tags, and identifying the questions with 2 paragraphs (1 long, 1 short) would probably make it run slow if I did it)</sub>

**Feature proposal**

I'd like to propose a quality filter that forces the askers to separate their questions into multiple paragraphs for long questions, so we can force askers to properly add paragraphs to their questions

*Example logic*:

IF (single paragraph AND paragraph length > 400)
OR (dual paragraph AND paragraph length first paragraph > 400 AND paragraph length second paragraph < 30 (likely *thx* or *gimmeh teh codez*))
THEN show message, reject submission of question.

*Example error message*:

You're asking a question using a single, very long paragraph. Questions like this are often hard to read, understand and answer. You need to add paragraphs to improve the readability of the question. To add a paragraph on Stack Overflow, you need to use *two* new lines (<kbd>Return ↵</kbd> key). For more tips on asking questions, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

<sup>note: writing UI messages is not my strong suit, just intended to illustrate the request and not to be taken too literally</sup>

<sup>1: Swanson, Charles E. "Readability and readership: A controlled experiment." Journalism Bulletin 25.4 (1948): 339-343.</sup>

Comment: Funnily enough, I was going to suggest much the same myself.  I searched SO meta for 'One sentence questions' ,'One line questions', 'Question length', and was unable to find any relevant matches.  Are there ANY of those short code-free questions that not a waste of bandwidth?  I suspect not, so I upvoted this request.

Comment: There are, so I posted a few links in support.  I won't post any more, and now eagerly await any contrary evidence that any such short questions are worth posting on SO.

Comment: Yuck, lousy examples.  Consider rolling that back and adding some real examples of stream-of-conscience questions that can't be fixed with a simple edit.

Comment: @HansPassant the point is not to auto-close or remove these questions, but to force the users posting them to edit them (saving time for the editors, saving them from downvotes, making it easier for people wanting to answer them to understand what's going on). I'm not saying that all long, single paragraph questions should be closed, but they probably all should be edited, and why not let the OP do that before posting it?

Comment: You have my vote. Edit: But the *"reject submission of question"* that wouldn't be too wise I feel.

Comment: Well, you already removed them:)   My examples were indeed of a wider range than yours, so fine:)   I'll keep track of them anyway, just to see how many get improved by an OP edit.  I don't want to waste time on closing questions either, and if they can be edited before  submission, fine, (though that is crossing over in to the 'submission template' issue:).

Comment: @HansPassant A SEDE query is even better than hand-picked examples, I think. I can remove that last example if you think it's not helping.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mean like the usual thing on a quality filter: you get an error message, and can't submit the question unless you edit it. That's also what happens for code-only questions and such.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I thought the idea to be a good one, but to reject it if they don't comply would not be well-accepted. Least, that's what I think and will most likely not go off too well and might even raise a certain amout of frustration. It may be a good idea if you were to edit your post for this. A warning box is good, but not to reject the post.

Comment: The idea is good, but the block is so easily circumvented it is just not worth the effort. Just add a single break and you've successfully beaten the nag. You can't force people to apply thought and care to their writing, you have to want to do it all on your own. A couple of downvotes on your lazy attempts are a better teacher, IMO.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is what the current quality filter does (and that does cause some annoyance for the code-only filter mainly, I've seen questions just appending a's or otherwise to bypass it). I'm all open for an optional warning box, but since this could be incorporated in the existing filters and I haven't seen optional warnings based on content yet

Comment: I agree with @Gimby 's comment. What I do in cases like this, where an OP constantly uses clumps of text is that, I will edit the post and insert a comment note, and also include a comment under their post about it, stating that clumps of text are very hard to read and that (some) people may not bother to continue reading after the first sentence. I am like that myself. If I have a hard time reading something, then I am pretty sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Gimby It's easy to circumvent, that's certainly true. But even adding a single extra line break in a long paragraph increases readability by a lot (for me, at least, I'm non-English), so mission achieved if they do that, I'd say. For me, it's mostly about being able to quickly understand the questions, and moderate or answer them appropriately (even closing a long single paragraph question with the appropriate vote is more difficult to me)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth *"and moderate"* - Ouuuhh I wouldn't go as far as (flag for) moderation, if that's what you meant by that. Your flag will most likely be declined and given an added note by the moderator who handled it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I mean edit, vote, close, and flag if appropriate, not mod-flag. Ofc I don't mod-flag these

Comment: I agree to add filtering like this, but only if you show an example of a properly formatted question (not just for readability, but maybe even with a breakdown of the specific things to write down in each paragraph.. like 'current situation', 'what I want to do', 'where it goes wrong') or something similar which would include even more variations of questions.

Part of being a great platform for questions and answers is teaching people how to properly ask questions.

Comment: @HenryvanMegen What do you mean? Do you want an example of a bad question edited into shape? Or do you want me to edit my question and add paragraphs according to your suggestions? Is it a suggestion for the message?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think rejecting it is good, but with the rejection the system would need to display a message that having long paragraphed questions are harder to read than properly divided pieces of text and also display a link to the generic "how to write a proper question" page. This page should have the properly divided & more readable paragraphs clearly visible as an example.

Comment: @HenryvanMegen Ah, I understand, and fully agree with that. The existing messages on quality filters are quite clear, and of course this one should be accompanied by a clear message as well.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth sorry for being unclear earlier.. this cold I have is giving me a splitting headache rendering me unable to think and formulate my answers clearly..

Comment: I love to see it happen, cause I also many times edited this type of question (Just Added Paragraphs to read it clear)

Comment: Note that most people posing single-paragraph questions actually put newlines in it.  They just don't put *TWO* newlines in it, which SO requires for a paragraph break.  A simple hint at submission time may be enough to increase quality significantly.

Comment: Related: *[Wall of text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wall_of_text)*

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth my point is that a paragraph is not formed just by putting a break somewhere, a paragraph represents a logical split in information which requires (re-)writing the text in a way that the break creates a logical reading flow. This check is easily circumvented just by putting a break anywhere and creating a single paragraph with a hole in it.

Comment: @Yakk: There is a live preview of the question, while you type. And a link to the formatting help. Do we really need any more hints?

Comment: @iinspectable clearly yes by the frequency it happens.

Comment: @Yakk: My point is that I do not understand why a hint would help any, after a user has already ignored two immediately accessible hints.

Comment: @IInspectable Because those hints are ignorable as they occur off the main flow of the questioners effort, while one that pops up in the middle of the workflow intrudes itself upon the main flow.

Answer (score 2):

While I personally agree that such block-styled questions can - more often than not - be improved with a select linebreak or 5, it is just that: *a personal preference*.

It is entirely feasible that a single-paragraph question can be standalone. Just like any form of statistics, the results we see here are easily skewed, but I propose: We see many problematic single-paragraph questions **due to newer users**. For example, let's breakdown your linked example and those produced (as of today) by the SEDE.

```
╔═════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║     User        ║         Question           ║
╠══════╦══════════╣                            ║
║ Rep. ║ Member   ║          Status            ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║    1 ║ ~3 years ║ On Hold (off-topic)        ║
║ 1548 ║ ~8 years ║ Open (Reasonable)          ║
║   10 ║ ~1 year  ║ Open (False Positive)      ║
║  163 ║ ~7 years ║ Open (Reasonable)          ║
║    4 ║  5 days  ║ On Hold (unclear)          ║
║   18 ║ ~4 years ║ Open (Needs Improvement)   ║
║    1 ║  6 days  ║ Close Votes x2 (too broad) ║
║   14 ║ ~2 years ║ On Hold (off-topic)        ║
║   13 ║ 25 days  ║ Close Votes x1 (unclear)   ║
║ 3867 ║ ~9 years ║ Open (Reasonable)          ║
╚══════╩══════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Derive what you want from such an unrealistically small sample size. Aside from the single false-positive (which arguably still needs some editing), there's a distinct pattern (in my opinion) of what needs improvement and what's OK:

1. User < 4 years: Closed or Closing
2. User ~ 4 years: Debateable
3. User > 4 years: Reasonable

So it's a question of volume. How many questions of this nature fall into each of the 3 categories above? Without any numbers, I'd assume the first - younger user accounts. This raises several questions:

- Is that enough to institute some arbitrary paragraph length rule on the rest of the user base?
- Does implementing such a solution justify the work saved on normal users?
- Is this actually an user-education issue?

---

> I'd like to propose a quality filter that forces the askers to separate their questions into multiple paragraphs for long questions [...].

While I do believe there is improvement to be made, I'm not sure that this is the path to take.

Currently, a proactive new user will find that we have guidelines for [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) effective questions. In the closing topic *Look for help asking for help*, is a link to Jon Skeet's coding blog titled [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Under the section *Spelling, grammar and formatting*, Jon bullet-points several rules for writing "*reasonably* correct English", including:

> Please split your text into paragraphs. Imagine this blog post as one big paragraph – it would be almost impossible to read.

Is it feasible to expect all new users to dive these several layers deep to get this suggestion? Perhaps not. But I would lean more towards a feature request geared towards new-user education<sup>1</sup> versus imposing a mandatory linebreak rule.

Besides, if a question isn't easily understandable then we have plentiful options already in place. Aside from editing: commenting, downvoting, close-voting, or simply skipping the question realistically takes seconds.

---

<sub>1: Also see user [Yakk's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359108/add-a-quality-filter-for-single-long-paragraph-questions?cb=1#comment530621_359108) on SO's (2-newline = 1-linebreak) requirement.</sub>

Comment: You're making a lot of valid points, but I disagree with one of them: I believe it's not just a _personal preference_, but a big improvement in readability for lots of users, and thus improves the accessibility and quality of the site (the ones you marked as _Reasonable_ could still benefit from extra paragraphs in my opinion). I agree it's partially a user-education issue (more in the domain of general writing than Stack Overflow), but so are most quality filters. And most are also arbitrary rules, they just aren't public or discussed.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth To be fair on two points: I agree, a linebreak could improve the *Reasonable* posts - but I hesitate to *require* it; secondly, I'm honestly not familiar with most quality filters - so you may have me there.

Comment: The quality filters are a bit of a mystical part of Stack Overflow. I mostly know them by trying to edit questions from users that are actively bypassing them. For example, I believe that there's one that you can't have a long, almost 100% code question, which I see bypassed by users just appending _this is not code_ repeated x times to the end of their question, or removing code formatting from the last code block (annoyingly, you can't just correct or remove these things by editing because they're also in effect on edits).

Comment: Note that the _false positive_ bugged me more than it should, so I did some digging. It was a post that perfectly met the filter, but then was edited by the original author after SEDE got it's data update (a good candidate for a message, though he figured it out himself).