# Is it ok to edit a long text without new lines to paragraphs?

Tags: discussion, edits

Personally I find it hard to read posts that have over 6 lines written without new lines. So when I see one I want to split it in to paragraphs.

Earlier when my edits were reviewed some of my edits to paragraphs were rejected with a reason

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read ...
>   ... or actively harm readability.

and some not.

I understand that this might be a bit off topic question and might collect opinion based or at best only some thumb rule answers (if any) but based on my before mentioned edit review experience and the fact that my edits are no more reviewed, to avoid making possible harm:

Does splitting long text in post to paragraphs make post even harder to read? (*please note that this question is **not** about asking "Why was my edit rejected?"*)

My idea of paragraphing is not like restricting the amount of lines to -say 6- but of course maintain the integrity of what paragraphs content is about.

Posts in Stack Overflow are mostly quite technical in nature and when the paragraphs grow very long it also indicates that there might be some other things to edit/fix also (like removing things like "*I've been struggling with this for a month now*"...).

And sometimes there are things like "*on the other hand*", "*from another point of view*" that provide good splitting point.

Comment: Was that all you did – leaving other quite obvious possible edits? Some reviewers would reject for that reason. (Now you cross the 2K, congratulations! You can edit at will. But Use Your Power With Responsibility.)

Comment: I sometimes do that as well, but then as part of a larger edit of the post.   If that is the only edit you do, you might get it rejected.

Comment: @usr2564301 It might not be all what I did in all cases but I almost certainly did nothing else that would harm readability. Of course it might have been that reviewer just picked any reason to reject. On the other hand many of my edits have been also improved. Mostly I think edit might have been thought then "superfluous" or something. But anyway the point in my question is more like that is it a bad habit in general and so how to use this privilege responsible.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes I understand the reason for reject is sometimes what you you told but now that I can do it without reject I ponder in my question should I.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359108/2564301 – in particular, the quote from https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/: "Please split your text into paragraphs. Imagine this blog post as one big paragraph – it would be almost impossible to read."

Comment: Maybe some writing systems don't have a concept of paragraphs ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Related question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355355/should-questions-and-answers-in-which-the-only-problem-is-the-first-person-singu/355356#355356

Comment: Paragraph length is something that should be thought about when writing, but it's *not*: After N lines insert a blank line. The way that you've written your question, it sounds like you're inserting lines *just* to break up chunks of text without regard to the text forming paragraphs. Paragraphs organize sentences into groups which share the same (very small) subject. Often the first sentence of a paragraph will provide a "subject" for the paragraph. If you are editing into grammatical paragraphs, that's great. If you're just sticking line-breaks in because it's been N lines, that's bad.

Comment: @Makyen I agree on what you say about criteria for paragraphs. I will also update question so that it will not give -for example- the picture that _in my opinion paragraphs maximum height is 6 lines_ or so.

Comment: On most sites it's accepted but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21634667) on SO a [big blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685713/mp3-files-corrupted-after-transfer-to-old-phone) might be rejected after review by two high enough Rep users for the same reason: "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier ..." - It was *only* worth the effort for the benefit of others in Charcoal HQ where it appeared, but not worth the reject by people whom carefully reviewed my edit. I'll wait until I'm 2K for my next edit, and leave it to them.

Comment: @Rob Your edit wasn't rejected because it didn't improve the post, at all. It was declined because having it approved *at that time* would have resulted in the post being put in the reopen queue without making the post on-topic. This would have usurped the OP's one entry-by-edit into the reopen queue to no benefit. It's clear you didn't intend that to be the case, as you made your suggested edit prior to the post being closed, but by the time it was being reviewed, the post was already closed. (continued)

Comment: @ rob (continued) I would have rejected the edit too, although, when doing so, I normally provide a custom reason to explain. However, the custom suggested-edit reject reasons are not permitted to be all that long, so the explanation is brief. Unfortunately, this is one of the potential hazards of editing off-topic posts. Note: You can prevent your edit from putting the post into the reopen queue by flagging the post for closure prior to editing. If you mentioned that you also flagged for closure in your edit comment, I'd approve that edit.

Comment: @Makyen - Thanks. I appreciate that on busy sites there can be a lot to wade through. I was interested in making the new user's post more readable (partly for Charcoalers) because it was in our queue. The enhanced readability made it easier to see that it was unwanted. There was some spelling I could have improved too, so my *fixing* was less than golden.

Comment: @rob The edit, had it been reviewed prior to the question being closed, was good and very likely would have been approved. The *only* reason that the edit was rejected was the issue of putting the question into the Reopen Queue without making it on-topic. The only thing you could've done was flagging for closure and mentioning the flag in your edit summary (and also saying your edit won't put the Q in the reopen queue). I know the two reviewers. The Reopen Queue issue *is* the reason your edit was rejected. If you want to, you can contact them in [SOCVR](//chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570).